# Android 11 (30 API) File.listFiles() doesn't return all files

Tags: android, android-file, filefilter

So I tested 29 and 30 Android API devices. Both has Download folder with 5 files (equal for both devices).

App has `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />` in manifest and requests it in runtime.

Also includes `android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"` (which is only for Android 10, Android 11 ignores it)

```
private fun init() {
    val path = File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "Download")
    val files = path.listFiles()
    Timber.d("Android API ${Build.VERSION.SDK_INT}, dirFiles \n${files?.joinToString(separator = "\n") { it.name }}")
}
```

Android 11 (30 SDK):

```
2021-10-06 23:40:52.182 9022-9022/com.example.tests D/MainActivity: Android API 30, dirFiles 
    Elephants Dream.srt
    Elephants Dream.mkv
```

Android 10 (29 SDK):

```
2021-10-06 23:45:51.835 8293-8293/com.example.tests D/MainActivity: Android API 29, dirFiles 
    Elephants Dream.srt
    Elephants Dream.ssa
    Elephants Dream.vtt
    Elephants Dream.ass
    Elephants Dream.mkv
```

As you can see Android 11 doesn't return all files using `File.listFiles()` method.

It filters files on system level by some Media filter. p.s. `MediaStore` cursor query returns same limited results

It recognizes that `srt` format subtitles file is media type, but `ssa`, `vtt` or `ass` subtitles file aren't media!

Quite weird logic. `ssa`, `vtt`, `ass` are also subtitles!

For Android 10 READ or WRITE storage permissions looks like this in the settings:

[image]

For Android 11 READ or WRITE storage looks like this:

[image]

I have an video player app which has to support many subtitles formats but I can only get `srt` on Android 11.

How to get all needed files?

**UPDATE**

Seems the only way for Android 11 is **Request All files access** https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/manage-all-files#all-files-access

But it will be challenging to be approved by Google

We could use SAF (Storage Access Framework) but it has many limitations for Android 11 https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared/documents-files#document-tree-access-restrictions

[image]

Comment: An app on an Android 11 device can only list its own files. Or media files in specific directories

Comment: @blackapps so to support more files I have to use https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/manage-all-files anyway?

Comment: Yes request all files access. Or use SAF to let the user select a directory with ACTION_OPEN_DICUMENT_TREE. After that you have access to all files in that directory.

Comment: @blackapps I think SAF won't be friendly for users at all, they have to pick the right directory (root), a video player just has to be able to access all videos and subtitles on the storage, so I'm going to implement `MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`

Comment: Even with SAF you cannot pick the root anymore nowadays.

Comment: @blackapps does it mean that I can only pick a specific subfolder from external root storage using SAF but not all files and subfolders of that external root storage?

Comment: @blackapps I tried to upload an app update with `MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` but it was rejected, they said it is not required for the core of the app. App only shows toast explaining why it needs this permission when it opens Settings automatically to enabled it. I will try to add an alert dialog with more clear explanation with button to go to settings to enable it. But I still think Google won't give it to me easily

Comment: SAF limitations for Andorid 11 are really bad, so it's quite useless for my app https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared/documents-files#document-tree-access-restrictions

Comment: Yes on an Android 11 device wirh SAF the root of external storage cannot be picked anymore. Nor Download directory. That is the limitation. Please name them! And everybody knows the rejecting by google.

Comment: @blackapps I think it's not possible to access all files for video player apps. Google won't accept that permission for such apps, it's only for apps like file explorer/manager, antivirus. Interesting how VLC player is going solve it. They still use 29 SDK https://github.com/videolan/vlc-android/blob/libvlc-3.4.3/build.gradle#L41

Comment: Android new file permissions is a steaming pile of crap!
They've f***ed up their OS and I'm not going to bother with it anymore.

Comment: @blackapps VLC has been approved  by google for `MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission, my app was rejected as I said before. Both their and my apps use libVLC to play different format of videos and subtitles

Answer (score 0, accepted):

VLC media player uses `android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` (All files access) permission now https://github.com/videolan/vlc-android/blob/89c2deb5fd4983dd64e0e55bc5ab8e559612c9d9/application/vlc-android/AndroidManifest.xml#L12

So this is the only way to access all types/formats of subtitles and videos but the only problem if Google will allow and approve such permission for your app.

Usually this permission can be used without any problems in such apps like file browsers, antivirus scan and so on, but official docs say nothing about media players.

There are new Media permissions (for video, audio, image) but they are useless, video media permission doesn't see all available video formats, only general ones, and there is no subtitle permission so the app could access srt, ass, vtt and other formats of subtitles.

So VLC app update with all file access permission was approved by Google but my video player app was rejected as I said before in the comments. Both VLC and my app use libVLC to play different format of videos and subtitles but permission can be used by not each app of the same category...

https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/manage-all-files

[image]

Answer (score 0):

this solution worked for me.

In the manifest add the permission:

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

In the activity, in the onStart() method, place the dynamic request for the permission:

```
    @Override
protected void onStart() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.R && !Environment.isExternalStorageManager()) {
        Uri uri = Uri.parse("package:" + BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID);
        Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_APP_ALL_FILES_ACCESS_PERMISSION, uri);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        this.getApplicationContext().startActivity(intent);
    }
    super.onStart();
}
```

Comment: Google approves only specific apps with this permission or if it's popular like VLC